# c++ getline does not seem to recognize newlines in input piped to stdin

Tags: c++, getline

This code:

$ cat junk.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string line;

    while(getline(cin, line)) 
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

works fine if I run it, then type "hi" and "there

$ junk
hi
hi
there
there

So far so good.

But I have another program:

$ cat junk1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 4;

    while(i--)
    {
        printf("abc\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This one outputs 4 lines of "abc\n" and sleeps after each line.

So if I do this:

junk1 | junk

I would expect to see each line of "abc" followed by a 1 second sleep, but instead I see 4 seconds of sleep followed by all 4 "abc" lines at the end.

Apparently getline() is buffering all output from junk1, and only proceding when junk1 terminates.

This is not the behavior I need, because I want to pipe the stdout from a program that runs forever and produces voluminous output, to a program like junk.cpp.

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by `stdout` in `junk1.c` being buffered: all writes to it (by `printf` or any other means) are collected in an in-memory buffer, and only written to `stdout` when the program exits.

To force `stdout` to actually write what it has in the buffer, you have to use `flush` (in your case, you should use it after every `printf`).

Comment: Also note that you probably won't see this behavior when testing `junk1` by itself, because if stdout goes to a terminal it will be line-buffered by default. Piping the output results in full buffering.

Comment: Excellent answers and that fixed it.  I totally forgot about buffered output.  Thanks!!!